Is the complex function $e^\sqrt{x}+e^{-\sqrt{x}}$ differentiable at $x=0$
For the function $p:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ where $p(z)=e^\sqrt{z}+e^{-\sqrt{z}}$, is it differentiable at $z=0$?
I've tried to use the definition of differentiable (ie,$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{p(z+h)-p(z)}{h}$) to find the derivative, but I don't know how to find this limit in the complex case. Cauchy-Riemann conditions don't work here because it is very difficult to write $p$
as $u+iv$

Yes, this function has an entire extension; look closely at the power series for $\cosh(z)$ and investigate which terms in the series vanish. (Hint: evenness/oddness is helpful).

@Conrad typo: $z^n$ in the numerator

@peek-a -boo - yes of course let me rewrite and thanks! $2\cosh \sqrt z=2\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{z^{n}}{(2n)!}$

Minor quibble: $~\sqrt{z}~$ is (potentially) ambiguous, depending on the convention used.  However, the presence of the expressions $~\sqrt{z}~$ and $~-\sqrt{z}~$ strongly suggest that (when $~z \neq 0~$) both roots $~w_1, ~w_2~$ should be used, where these represent the two distinct roots of the equation $~w^2 = z.$
